# Can't Load Many Pictures from Graph API at Once

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, preloader, facebook-oauth

I am trying to preload images for a visual Facebook app, but when I try to preload them half don't get loaded with this error:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 4
   }
}

There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this.... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How are you loading the images? are you requesting multiple objects in a single call, using the batch API, making FQL queries, etc? Because the limits are per-access-token, you should be able to work around them pretty easily with modifications to your code

Comment: I'm just loading in images <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/615719/picture?type=large"> with jquery append one at a time based on information in my server...  I know there must be limits but I can't seem to find any in the documentation to know how/when to space out my calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above, you're making a separate request for each individual image which is why you're hitting a rate limit, you should request them in bulk, easiest way is to do something like (the exact syntax is language/SDK specific)
`https://graph.facebook.com?fields=picture&type=large&ids=COMMA_SEPERATED_LIST_OF_USER_IDs&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

The response format from this is:

```
{
  "4": {
    "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/49942_4_1525300_n.jpg"
  }, 
  // Other users you included in the IDs parameter
}
```

(but all the SDKs will wrap that and make it easier to iterate over)

Comment: just curious - does anyone know where I could find the actual rules about rate limits for the graph api?  it doesn't seem to be explicitly laid out anywhere.

Comment: No, it's not documented publicly as far as I know as it could change and it's a limit, not a target, but it's currently 600 calls per 600 seconds per access token - not using an access token means you get a limit per IP but i'm not sure what that limit is